# Autoencoder with 3D convolutions and convolutional LSTMs

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, keras-layer, autoencoder

I have implemented a variational autoencoder with CNN layers in the encoder and decoder. The code is shown below. My training data (`train_X`) consists of 40'000 images with size 64 x 80 x 1 and my validation data (`valid_X`) consists of 4500 images of size 64 x 80 x 1.

I would like to adapt my network in the following two ways:

1. Instead of using 2D convolutions (Conv2D and Conv2DTranspose) I would like to use 3D convolutions to take time into account (as the third dimension). For that I would like to use slices of 10 images, i.e. I will have images of size 64 x 80 x 1 x 10. Can I just use Conv3D and Conv3DTranspose or are other changes necessary?
2. I would like to try out convolutional LSTMs (ConvLSTM2D) in the encoder and decoder instead of plain 2D convolutions. Again, the input size of the images would be 64 x 80 x 1 x 10 (i.e. time series of 10 images). How can I adapt my network to work with ConvLSTM2D?

```
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import (Dense, Input, Flatten)
from keras.layers import Lambda, Conv2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Reshape, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.losses import mse

def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    batch = K.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = K.int_shape(z_mean)[1]
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    return z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

inner_dim = 16
latent_dim = 6

image_size = (64,78,1)
inputs = Input(shape=image_size, name='encoder_input')
x = inputs

x = Conv2D(32, 3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, 3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

# shape info needed to build decoder model
shape = K.int_shape(x)

# generate latent vector Q(z|X)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(inner_dim, activation='relu')(x)
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_mean')(x)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(x)

z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])

# instantiate encoder model
encoder = Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')

# build decoder model
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
x = Dense(inner_dim, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
x = Dense(shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3], activation='relu')(x)
x = Reshape((shape[1], shape[2], shape[3]))(x)

x = Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

outputs = Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='decoder_output')(x)

# instantiate decoder model
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')

# instantiate VAE model
outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
vae = Model(inputs, outputs, name='vae')

def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):
    reconstruction_loss = mse(K.flatten(x), K.flatten(x_decoded_mean))
    reconstruction_loss *= image_size[0] * image_size[1]
    kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)
    kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
    kl_loss *= -0.5
    vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
    return vae_loss

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.000)
vae.compile(loss=vae_loss, optimizer=optimizer)
vae.fit(train_X, train_X,
        epochs=500,
        batch_size=128,
        verbose=1,
        shuffle=True,
        validation_data=(valid_X, valid_X))
```

Thank you very much for the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have your input shape as `(10, 64 , 80, 1)` and just replace the layers.

The boring part is to organize the input data, if you're going to use sliding windows or just reshape from `(images, 64,80,1)` to `(images//10, 10, 64,80,1)`.

### Sliding windows (Overlapping) or not?

1 - Ok.... if you want your model to understand individual segments of 10 images you may overlap or not. Your choice. Performance may be better with overlapping, but not necessarily.

There isn't really an order in the images, as long as the 10 frames are in order.

This is supported by `Conv3D` and by `LSTM` with `stateful=False`.

2 - But if you want your model to understand the entire sequence, dividing the sequences only because of memory, only `LSTM` with `stateful=True` can support this.

(A `Conv3D` with kernel size = `(frames, w, h)` will work, but limited to `frames`, never understanding sequences longer than `frames`. It may still be capable of detecting the existence of punctual events, though, but not long sequence relationships)

In this case, for the `LSTM` you will need to:

- set `shuffle = False` in training
- use a fixed batch size of `sequences`
- **not overlap** images
- create a manual training loop where you do `model.reset_states()` every time you are giving "new sequences" for training AND predicting

The loop structure would be:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for group_of_sequences in range(groups):
        model.reset_states()

        sequences = getAGroupOfCompleteSequences() #shape (sequences, total_length, ....)            

        for batch in range(slide_divisions):
            batch = sequences[:,10*batch : 10*(batch+1)]

            model.train_on_batch(batch, ....)
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I will create create a matrix (images//10, 10, 64,80,1), for example (4000, 10, 64,80,1). I think for LSTM also the order matters. Is the input processed by (1, 10, 64,80,1), (2, 10, 64,80,1), (3, 10, 64,80,1) etc? Moreover, should the images in a sequence be unique or should the images in the sequences overlap? With overlapping I mean for example seq1=(im1,im2,im3,...,im10) and seq2=(im5,im6,im7,...,im14).

Comment: The order is `(:,0,:,:,:)`, `(:,1,:,:,:)`, `(:,2,:,:,:)` .... ---- The data organization is your decision. If you think every group of 10 images form intelligible sequences, you can do the sliding windows as you proposed.

Comment: You mean the overlapping or non overlapping sliding windows? Regarding the order, (:,0,:,:,:), (:,1,:,:,:),..., (:,10,:,:,:) is the order within a Conv3D or ConvLSTM unit but when I use a batch size of for example 128 what is the order in such a batch? I'm asking because I have sequences of 700 images (forming one video) but I have to split this sequences into smaller chunks (e.g. 10 images) due to memory constraints, training time etc. But of course when I split the sequence of 700 images into chunks of 10 images, the order they are consumed matters...

Comment: Please see answer for details.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm currently implementing it. Let's say I have a batch size of 100 and my sequence is of size 980. In the last batch I would only have 80 images. What should I do in such a situation? Just skipping the 80 images?

Comment: WIth `stateful=True` you must have a fixed batch shape, there is no escape. You can mix data from other batches to complete the missing entries. Or you can use a number that divides the data perfectly. Without `stateful=True`, no worries, it will simply work.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Could I also add 20 black or white images (all 0 or all 1) to the end of the sequence or is this not recommended?

Comment: I think it may affect training. Probably a random sample from other images would be better.

Comment: My implementation is almost finished and working. Just one last question. How many filter should I use in the very last layer with the sigmoid activation? Currently I'm using 1 filter.

Comment: The same as the output data channels.

Comment: Do you mean when the output is (80, 64, 1), i.e. one color channel, using one filter?